# Why do carets vanish when calling a batch file from powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping

Here's my `args.bat` file:

```
@echo off
python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" %*
```

I'm invoking python here because I know exactly how to interpret output, rather than guessing which quotes are in the string

Here's what happens if I invoke it from cmd:

```
>.\args.bat ^^^^^
More?
More?
['-c', '^']
>.\args.bat "^^^^^"
['-c', '^^^^^']
```

But here's what powershell does:

```
PS> .\args.bat ^^^^^
['-c', '^']
PS> .\args.bat "^^^^^"
['-c', '^']
PS> .\args.bat '^^^^^'
['-c', '^']
PS> .\args.bat "'^^^^^'"
['-c', '^']
PS> .\args.bat '"^^^^^"'
['-c', '^^^^^']
```

Why do I have to doubly-quote the argument when calling a batch file from powershell?

---

The same problem doesn't exist calling python from powershell:

```
PS> python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" "^^^^^"
['-c', '^^^^^']
PS> python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" '^^^^^'
['-c', '^^^^^']
PS> python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" ^^^^^
['-c', '^^^^^']
```

But persists when calling batch from python from powershell!

```
PS> python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['args.bat', '^^^^^'])"
['-c', '^']
```

And batch from python from cmd:

```
> python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['args.bat', '^^^^^'])"
['-c', '^']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the larger question of **whether batch files can robustly relay arbitrary arguments** (spoiler alert: no), see Eric's [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51759330/102441).

---

**tl;dr**:

```
PS> .\args.bat --% "^^^^^"
['-c', '^^^^^']
```

Using [`--%`, the stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), makes PowerShell pass the remaining arguments through as-is, except for expanding `cmd.exe`-style environment variable references such as `%OS%`.

Conversely, you won't able to reference *PowerShell* variables or expressions.

---

**PowerShell**, as a shell in its own right, performs its *own* parsing first and then - an unfortunate necessity on *Windows* - ***reapplies quoting* when composing a command line for an *external program***.

The way it does that has changed over time and has been the source of many problems in the past.
These problems led to the introduction of `--%`, as described above, which has its own challenges, however.

The re-quoting is generally a necessity, however, given that PowerShell's syntax isn't necessarily understood by external programs.
Most notably, `'...'` quoting cannot be assumed to be understood by all external programs and therefore requires transforming to `"..."`.

However, PowerShell re-quotes *conditionally*, based on whether it thinks it is *necessary*.

In the case at hand, because the *content* of the *PowerShell* `"^^^^^"` string contains *no whitespace*, PowerShell decides *not to quote it* when passing it through to the batch file; i.e.:

```
.\args.bat "^^^^^"
```

effectively becomes

```
.\args.bat ^^^^^
```

This is fine for *most* external programs, where `^` has no *syntactic* meaning, but in the case of a batch file (interpreted by `cmd.exe`) it matters, because `^` function as the escape char. in unquoted strings there.

To still force the use double-quoting in this scenario, as an alternative to the `--%` approach above, you can use *embedded* double-quoting, as you've already demonstrated in your question:

```
PS> .\args.bat '"^^^^^"' #  '...' quoting with embedded "..." quoting
['-c', '^^^^^']
```

---

> The same problem doesn't exist calling python from powershell:
> `PS> python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" "^^^^^"`

That's because `cmd.exe` isn't involved in this scenario, and even though the enclosing double quotes are lost when calling from PowerShell, Python treats the `^` instances are as literals.

> But persists when calling batch from python from powershell
> `PS> python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['args.bat', '^^^^^'])"`
>
> And batch from python from cmd:
> `> python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call(['args.bat', '^^^^^'])"`

That's because you're again calling a *batch* file - with *unquoted* `^^^^^` in this case even from `cmd.exe`, because the enclosing `'....'` only have syntactical meaning to *Python* and aren't passed through - which reintroduces the special interpretation of `^`.

Note that **even "shell-less" methods of invoking a batch file (such as `subprocess.call()` from Python) still invariably invoke `cmd.exe`**, because `cmd.exe` is the interpreter required to execute batch files.

When passing an *unquoted* string `^^^^^` to a batch file, there seem to be 2 rounds of interpretation: first, as part of *argument parsing*, each `^^` pair becomes a single `^`, with any non-paired `^` getting discarded. *Inside the batch file*, you therefore see `^^`, which, when used unquoted, becomes a single `^` - if you double-quote `%*` or `%1` inside the batch file you'll see that `^^` was passed.